# Consulta Sql retorne o mesmo nome com data diferente

Tags: sql, query, group-by

Minha tabela `Acidente` é mais ou menos assim:

```
Vitima - DataRegistro
Pedro  - 10/02/2015 
Pedro  - 20/03/2015
Maria  - 01/05/2015
Maria  - 01/05/2015
```

Preciso fazer uma consulta (Sql) que me retorne os registros que contenham:

- Nome da vitima apareça mais de uma vez
- Com datas de registros diferentes (neste caso o ultimo registro não irá retornar na consulta)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa query só vai retornar *Vitimas* que apareçam pelo menos mais de uma vez e com datas diferentes, lembrando que o correto seria você buscar pelo `ID` da Vítima e não nome pois pode repetir.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1.* FROM Acidentes a1
INNER JOIN Acidentes a2 ON a1.Vitima = a2.Vitima AND a1.DataRegistro <> a2.DataRegistro
```

### [SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b33b/4/0)

Comment: Maicon, bom dia.

Muito obrigado pela ajuda, fiquei quebrando a cabeça sexta até tarde com esse relatório.. 

abrass